# Getting error on extension method for CheckedListBox - CS0201

Tags: c#, winforms, extension-methods, checkedlistbox

I have an extension method for a CheckedListBox which adjusts the column width depending on content. The following method is placed in a separate ExtensionMethods class:

```
public static void AdjustCheckedListWidthToContent(this CheckedListBox checkedListBox)
{
    int maxWidth = 0;
    foreach (string text in checkedListBox.Items)
    {
        int width = TextRenderer.MeasureText(text, checkedListBox.Font).Width;
        if (width > maxWidth)
            maxWidth = width;
    }
    checkedListBox.ColumnWidth = maxWidth + 20;
}
```

This way the code works fine:
`ExtensionMethods.AdjustCheckedListWidthToContent(checkedListBoxProductList);`

But in my preferred way, I'm getting error - CS0201  C# Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement:
`checkedListBoxProductList.AdjustCheckedListWidthToContent;`

I can't get my head around. :(

Comment: Have you tried `checkedListBoxProductList.AdjustCheckedListWidthToContent()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a pair of parentheses before semicolon. It is required even there's no parameter in a function call statememnt.

Comment: So trivial, as always.. :) Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

As i remember this is not a valid method signature.

```
AdjustCheckedListWidthToContent(this CheckedListBox checkedListBox)
```

It should be

```
AdjustCheckedListWidthToContent(CheckedListBox checkedListBox)
```

Comment: [Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)